# How do i skip a Github action?

Tags: github-actions

I want to apply an if condition on the whole composite action rather than on individual steps.It would be great to skip the action for dependabot for example. I can add an if statement at the workflow level but I am wondering if it is possible at the action level.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runsstepsshell

Sample example:

```
name: 'Hello World'
description: 'Greet someone'
inputs:
  who-to-greet:  # id of input
    description: 'Who to greet'
    required: true
    default: 'World'
outputs:
  random-number:
    description: "Random number"
    value: ${{ steps.random-number-generator.outputs.random-number }}
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - run: echo Hello ${{ inputs.who-to-greet }}.
      shell: bash
    - id: random-number-generator
      run: echo "random-number=$(echo $RANDOM)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      shell: bash
    - run: echo "${{ github.action_path }}" >> $GITHUB_PATH
      shell: bash
    - run: goodbye.sh
      shell: bash
```

Can composite action have if statement at root level to skip it ?

```
name: 'Hello World'
description: 'Greet someone'
inputs:
  who-to-greet:  # id of input
    description: 'Who to greet'
    required: true
    default: 'World'
outputs:
  random-number:
    description: "Random number"
    value: ${{ steps.random-number-generator.outputs.random-number }}
runs:
  using: "composite"
  //if: github.actor != 'dependabot[bot]'
  steps:
    - run: echo Hello ${{ inputs.who-to-greet }}.
      shell: bash
    - id: random-number-generator
      run: echo "random-number=$(echo $RANDOM)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      shell: bash
    - run: echo "${{ github.action_path }}" >> $GITHUB_PATH
      shell: bash
    - run: goodbye.sh
      shell: bash
```

Comment: @tmt Adding a simple if for a job is simple but i haven't seen the feature for composite action

Comment: I would approach this by trial and error, so my first question has to be: did you test the obvious solution, and if so what was the outcome?

Comment: Also, I'd like to clarify the goal: your composite action is going to get invoked in some other workflow, which will expect it to run, but you want the action to auto-skip on some condition. Wouldn't that break the workflow that's depending on it? Can you provide an idea of your use case for this, to put your question in context?

Answer (score 2):

you could skip the whole job like:

```
  compliance-check:
    if: github.actor != 'dependabot[bot]'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
```

Comment: I am aware this is possible at workflow level but i want this in composite action. Check by edit for details